# Load/Performance testing a site with Kerberos authentication

Tags: kerberos, load-testing, performance-testing

Which performance testing tool supports web pages with Kerberos authentication?
Tools which just fallback to NTLM is not enough.

Comment: Though not the answer you're looking for, I can tell you Jmeter does NOT support Kerberos.

Comment: Did you see this article? http://securewebs.com/about/blog-page/load-and-performance-test-tools/ It seems to have most of what you're asking about.

Comment: I just added an enhancement request to JMeter: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53480

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done some research and the list of available tools are:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Load testing tools (part of the Ultimate package)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate)
- [Proxy Sniffer](http://www.proxy-sniffer.com)
- [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com)
- [Forecast](http://www.facilita.co.uk)

Answer (score 1):

I do these tests with [Silk Performer](http://www.borland.com/products/silkperformer/), which is a commercial product from Borland that manages hundreds of parallel test users connecting via Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter support KERBEROS very well.

Comment: To be fair to @Shay, Stack Overflow has changed a bit in the 4 years since this question has been asked. This question no longer meets SO requirements, and all of the answers are bad for the same reason yours is.

Answer (score 0):

WebLOAD from http://www.radview.com/ support Kerberos authentication